# Optimizing Nested mySQL Query... Or letting it run indefinitely

Tags: mysql, query-performance

We are able to buy "trunks" from our VOIP provider and any time we go over our trunks, we get billed (a pretty penny) per minute. The provider gives NO reporting features, so we are pretty much guessing what trunks we should be getting and we are frequently guessing very poorly. So, I've setup a DB that has all of our call records in it. Then I created a SQL query that will tell me many trunks we would have needed to complete the call (row) for "free". Here's the query I'm using:

```
USE cdrs;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdr_temp
AS (
    SELECT callrecords.Timestamp, callrecords.CallEnd, callrecords.CallDirection, callrecords.Rate
    FROM cdrs.callrecords
);

UPDATE cdrs.callrecords AS a
SET TrunksNeeded = (
    select count(CallID)
    FROM cdr_temp AS b
    WHERE b.Timestamp <= a.Timestamp
    AND b.CallEnd >= a.Timestamp
    AND b.CallDirection = a.CallDirection
    AND b.Rate > 0
)
WHERE TrunksNeeded IS NULL AND Rate > 0
LIMIT 50;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS cdr_temp;
```

Notice, the limit 50... For just 50 records this takes 50-80 seconds. I've tried optimizing using indexes. But nothing I do seems to help. Below is a show table dump:

```
CREATE TABLE 'callrecords' (
    'Timestamp' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    'AccountID' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    'CNAME' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    'To' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    'From' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    'CallDirection' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    'hangup_cause' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    'BillingSeconds' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    'DurationSeconds' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    'Rate' float DEFAULT NULL,
    'RateName' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    'Cost' float DEFAULT NULL,
    'CallID' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    'CallEnd' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    'TrunksNeeded' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    KEY 'idx_calldata' ('Timestamp','CallEnd','CallDirection','Rate')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

There's about 1.5 million records in the DB representing 90 days of call logs. And about 400k of them have a rate over 0. Meaning, they are billable, non-internal calls.

I have two questions.

1) Is there an easy way to change the table or the query I'm using to make the query run faster?

2) If not, by my calculations, it'll take 5 days to run the query against 30 days worth of records. I know it sounds crazy, but for the next year or so at least, I'm OK with that. Is there a way to issue this command so that it will eventually just complete in the background and ignore timeouts?

EDIT:
Adding an index to the temporary table as @Sentinel recommended helped a lot. Also, I noticed my HDD was maxing out. So I put the temp DB into memory and that was a huge improvement too. Looks like the query now will take a little under a day to run. But I'm still left with the question of how I can let a query run for that long...

Updated SQL Query:

```
USE cdrs;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdr_temp ENGINE=MEMORY
AS (
    SELECT callrecords.Timestamp, callrecords.CallEnd, callrecords.CallDirection, callrecords.Rate
    FROM cdrs.callrecords
);
alter table cdr_temp add index idx1 (CallDirection, rate, timestamp, callend);

UPDATE cdrs.callrecords AS a
SET TrunksNeeded = (
     select count(CallID)
     FROM cdr_temp AS b
     WHERE b.Timestamp <= a.Timestamp
     AND b.CallEnd >= a.Timestamp
     AND b.CallDirection = a.CallDirection
     AND b.Rate <> 0
)
WHERE TrunksNeeded IS NULL AND Rate <> 0
ORDER BY Timestamp
LIMIT 5000;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS cdr_temp;
```

Comment: A better way to civilize a slow `UPDATE`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: You may be able to squeeze out some additional performance gains by prefiltering the call records when instantiating the cdr_temp table.  Specifically you can `select ... from cdrs.callrecords where rate <> 0` to reduce the number of records you're working with in the `SET TrunksNeeded = (...)` subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the time you report may well be spent in instantiating your temp table `cdr_temp` which has no indexes on it to improve performance.

Have you tried not using the temp table:

```
UPDATE cdrs.callrecords AS a
SET TrunksNeeded = (
    select count(CallID)
    FROM cdrs.callrecords AS b
    WHERE b.Timestamp <= a.Timestamp
    AND b.CallEnd >= a.Timestamp
    AND b.CallDirection = a.CallDirection
    AND b.Rate <> 0
)
WHERE TrunksNeeded IS NULL AND Rate > 0
LIMIT 50;
```

You may also get better performance if you have an index on (CallDirection, Rate) especially if you test for `b.Rate <> 0` instead of `b.Rate > 0` since the query optimizer/planner may be able to eliminate more records before doing the range scans needed to check for overlapping calls.

To keep the temp table and add indexes to it (note the revised column order):

```
alter table cdr_temp add index idx1 (CallDirection, rate, timestamp, callend);
```

This will use the temp table, with the new index and has the code changes I recommended.

```
UPDATE callrecords AS a
SET TrunksNeeded = (
    select count(CallID)
    FROM cdr_temp AS b
    WHERE b.CallDirection = a.CallDirection
    AND b.Rate <> 0
    AND a.Timestamp BETWEEN b.Timestamp AND b.CallEnd
)
WHERE TrunksNeeded IS NULL AND Rate > 0
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Yea, that was my original idea. But I get this error when I try to execute...

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause 0.000 sec

Comment: Is it possible to copy indices over as well when creating a temp table maybe??

Comment: I tried adding indices to the temp table and performance is WAY worse..

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdr_temp LIKE cdrs.callrecords;

INSERT cdr_temp SELECT * FROM cdrs.callrecords;

Maybe because it's re-creating the index in the background instead of copying over existing index?

Comment: No, but you can add them after the fact: `alter table cdr_temp add index idx1 (CallDirection, rate, timestamp, callend);`

Comment: That halved my query time. Also put the temp db into memory because I noticed my HDD was pegged. That helped a bunch too. Looks like I can do the query in under a day now. But, still... how do I run a query that takes that long without hitting timeouts? I keep getting Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

Comment: It does still complete in the background! Also, I found the preference in MySQL workbench to extend the DBMS connection read time out. Between the two, I have a functional solution. It looks like it will still take a day to process all the data. But, that's more than acceptable for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Not sure why you changed WHERE b.Timestamp <= a.CallEnd. Timestamp represents the time of the beginning of the call. I'm thinking you are under the impression that it represents the time that the row was committed to the DB?

Comment: Upon further thought, with regards to changing `B.Timestamp <= A.Timestamp` to `B.Timestamp <= A.CallEnd`, keep it the way you had it, or change it to the equivalent `A.Timstamp between B.Timestamp and B.CallEnd` I've edited my response to remove the incorrect recommendation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I️ seriously appreciate you clarifying. I️ was really questioning myself.